# How the GRUB2 found a place of the erubenv file

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, grub2

I working on some programing project, and at the time i looking for an information about of : how the GRUB2 using the file /boot/grub/grubenv ?
 In particulary how the GRUB find the start LBA of the file before loading content of it ?

TIA.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GRUB use file system drivers to performs working on partition as usual.